# Bootstrap datepicker opens on form submit

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, datepicker

I am having weird issue where bootstrap datepicker opens up when i click on submit button of the form. I am using MVC 4.
below is my javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
           $('#startDate').datepicker({
               format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
               autoclose: true,
               todayBtn: true
           });

           $('#endDate').datepicker({
               format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
               autoclose: true,
               todayBtn: true
           });

           $('.chosen').chosen();

           $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
               $('#form1').submit();
           });
       });
```

And the HTML is

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Start Date</label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.From, new
           {
               @class = "form-control",
               @id = "startDate",
               @Value = Model.From.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
           })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">End Date</label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.To, new
           {
               @class = "form-control",
               @id = "endDate",
               @Value = Model.To.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
           })
            </div>
        </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index", "TradeActivityGroups", null, new { @class = "btn btn-danger" })
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btnSubmit">Submit</button>
        </div>
```

Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong.

Update:

This issue only occurs on Chrome and not any other browser.

Comment: You doing a submit, so I assume you must be returning the view. Are there any scripts which are run on page load that might trigger the datepicker to open? I dont know Bootstrap datepicker but it may be because your setting the value using `@Value = Model.From.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")` which will be different from what you posted if you selected a date in the initial page load.

Comment: No, there are no scripts on page load that triggers datepicker to open. Only scripts that exists on the page are the ones I have mentioned in the question.

Comment: When you first load the page (from the GET method), are the datepickers open? Try rendering the textboxes correctly `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.From, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "datepicker form-control" })` and then the script can be just `$('.datepicker').datepicker({format: 'dd/mm/yyyy', autoclose: true, todayBtn: true });`.

Comment: I noticed that this issue was fixed when I removed the date formatting

Answer (score 1):

remove format attribute of datepicker it may be conflicting with validation

Answer (score 0):

Try rewrite your `#btnSubmit` event handler in your JS like this:

```
$('#btnSubmit').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    $('#form1').submit();
});
```

the [stopImmediatePropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/) method will prevent any event bubling through the DOM, maybee it cause your problem. The [preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) prevents default handler of that element to trigger.